# $y' = (xy)^2$, DE, how to?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y' = (xy)^2$$

How do you solve this? I need to separate them somehow, but I know how to do it if I've got a product consisting of $x$, $y$, and something else (since I can move them around how I want), but when I expand that parentheses, I get $x^2 + y^2 + 2xy$.... ??

I have the same issue with $y' = xy - y$. Again, if it wasn't for the "$- y$" I know exactly what to do, but now...

Comment: Your algebra might be lacking a little  to learn differential equations.  In the first case, $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$. In the second one,  $ xy-y=(x-1)y$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: separate and integrate:

$$\int \dfrac{1}{y^2}~ dy = \int x^2 ~ dx$$

**Spoiler (hover)**

> $$y(x) = -\dfrac{3}{x^3 + c}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yours is equivalent to $\frac{dy}{dx} = x^2 y^2$. Now can you separate them?

Answer (score 1):

If your expand $(xy)^2$ it becomes $x^2y^2$. You can seperate that. And for the second part: divide by $y$, and it is separated.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation is separable, so we can employ the method "Separation of Variables".
$$y'=(xy)^2$$ 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2y^2$$
$$\frac{dy}{y^2}=x^2 \, dx$$
$$\int \frac{dy}{y^2}=\int x^2 \, dx$$
$$-\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{3}x^3+C$$
Now algebraically solving for $y$, we can express the solution as
$$y=-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{3}x^3+C}$$
or as (in a neater format)

### $$y=\frac{3}{C-x^3}$$

For $y'=xy-y$, we can factor out the $y$ on the right side and say
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(x-1)y$$
and separate the varaibles to get
$$\frac{dy}{y}=(x+1) \, dx$$
then integrate both sides.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how did you algebraically solve for y? What rule did you use to get it out from the denominator?

Comment: From $$-\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + C$$ I multiplied by $y$ on both sides and also divided by $\frac{1}{3}x^3 + C$ on both sides (cross-multiply), then by the negative sign on both sides. Hope that helps a little. :)